# Using Loops to Create Iterations of Graphic Objects

Tags: python, loops, zelle-graphics

I have looked around for an answer to this but cannot seem to find a solution. I'd like the word function to create 10 identical circles with center points that have the same y coordinates but different x coordinates so that their spacing is 25 from one center point to the other. The functions that I have created are only drawing one iteration of the object and I cannot figure out how to fix this. Thank you for any help.

I have tried to create two separate functions. One defines the loop function that I would like to print 10 circles while appending a list of circles. The other function calls upon the draw function to draw all 13 circles.

```
def draw(window):
    circles=[]
    for i in range(10):
        x=25
        circle=Circle(Point(0+x,370),10)
        circle.setFill("yellow")
        circles.append(circle)
        circle.draw(window)
    return circles
def circleRow():
    window=GraphWin("Window",400,400)
    window.setBackground("red")
    cicles1=draw(window)

circleRow()
```

I expected an output of 10 circles evenly spaced along the same y-coordinate but am only getting a single circle.

Comment: You need to use a different `x` value for each iteration in the loop. Initialize it outside the loop and do a `x += increment` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

We could replace the (unused) iteration variable `i` with `x` instead and explicitly describe what range of values it should take on:

```
from graphics import *

def draw(window):
    circles = []

    for x in range(25, 275, 25):
        circle = Circle(Point(x, 370), 10)
        circle.setFill('yellow')
        circle.draw(window)

        circles.append(circle)

    return circles

def circleRow():
    window = GraphWin("Window", 400, 400)
    window.setBackground('red')

    circles = draw(window)

    window.getMouse()
    window.close()

circleRow()
```

There are various other valid ways to approach this.